# SQL Server : Declare is causing problems in query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I currently have an issue with SQL Server which I can't figure out.

The error is:

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations

SQL:

```
DECLARE @IdUser INT 

Select 
    @IdUser = Id, 
    Username, 
    (Select Count(*) From GagsLikes where Userid = @IdUser And Good = 1) as GagLikes, 
    (Select Count(*) From GagsViews where UserID = @IdUser), 
    (Select Count(*) From Gags Where UserID = @IdUser) as GagViews 
From 
    Users  
Order by 
    GagLikes, GagViews
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As it says you may not combine this `@IdUser = Id` and the rest of your select.

Comment: What are you even trying to do here? You have no where clause, and I assume you have more than one user.. so what value are you expecting to assign to `@IdUser`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, it displays all the users with some of their information. Everything was working except for the sub queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not use that variable as you do it try this:

```
Select 
    U.Id, 
    U.Username, 
    (Select Count(*) From GagsLikes where Userid = U.Id And Good = 1) as GagLikes, 
    (Select Count(*) From GagsViews where UserID = U.Id), 
    (Select Count(*) From Gags Where UserID = U.Id) as GagViews 
From 
    Users AS U
Order by 
    GagLikes, GagViews
```

Answer (score 1):

your table might return more then one rows . make sure that your table return only one row otherwise it can
t store multiple id's in to one int variable .